# NServiceBus 4.03 Is there a way to preserve the message thrown to a wrong handler into some error q

Tags: handler, endpoint, nservicebus4

I have 5 different handlers running as NServiceBus host as windows service.

I had issue when my client send the message to a wrong endpoint(i.e. instead of endpoint A it pointed to endpoint B) which result message not getting processed (as expected). But is there anyway of preserving those message which cannot be processed by handler into some queue so that it can be manually passed on to a different q.

At the moment the message is lost and we cant do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you (try to) send a message to a non-existent queue, the queuing service puts it in the Dead-Letter Queue so it isn't lost.

If you send a message to the wrong queue from where some code swallows it without really processing it, then (as long as you haven't turned off auditing) that message will be forwarded to the audit queue in which case it isn't lost either.

In short, in both cases, you won't lose the message.

Comment: we dont have audit 'on' in production and we cant due to nature of messages which contain some sensitive information.

Is there a way 'in IMutators' to check if the message can be handled by the handler if not move to the error q or forward to  a different q ....

Comment: If your concern is about sensitive information being visible in the queues, define the necessary properties of those messages as being encrypted. Don't try to reimplement the functionality that already exists.